# Copy file action and Remote Event Receivers not getting a valid token

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, acs

I have two site collections (let call them `src` and `dest`)

In the `dest` site collection I have a remote event receiver that triggers whenever a document is updated in the default document library (ItemAdded, ItemAdding, ItemUpdated and ItemUpdating event are tracked).

This works perfectly when I work whithin the site collection `dest`.

However, if I copy a file from `src` to `dest` using the OOB *copy to* action, the RER fails, having in the payload this error:

> `Failed to get the context token for the remote event receiver url`.

After some tests, I land to the conclusion this is due to the browser session creating an auth token for the site `src` to call the copy file api.

Then the RER triggers using the context token for site `src` not site `dest` and fails because of that.

How to overcome this issue ?

Some details:

- the RER is registered using an application. It handles `AppInstalled` event to register the receivers onto the host site's document library under the RER app context.
- the code is written using an Azure Function (following s-kainet blog article)
- the error is taken from the incoming payload, in the `SPRemoteEventProperties.ErrorMessage` node
- The RER is built using the addin model (`.app` package), uploaded in the site collection's app catalog, then activated (from *add an app* menu)
- the manifest declare this permissions request :

  ```
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection"
                          Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
  ```

As I said, it's working perfectly when working within the `dest` site.

**[edit]** This occurs both in `-ing` and `-ed` events

**[edit2]** sample SOAP payloads:

Payload of the ItemAdded event, if file copy within the same site collection :

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ProcessOneWayEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/">
            <properties xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <AppEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <ContextToken>eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC .........</ContextToken>
                <CorrelationId>8d8d6ba0-f0d7-5000-72d5-187dc612d273</CorrelationId>
                <CultureLCID>1033</CultureLCID>
                <EntityInstanceEventProperties i:nil="true" />
                <ErrorCode />
                <ErrorMessage />
                <EventType>ItemAdded</EventType>
                <ItemEventProperties>
                    <AfterProperties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                        <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                            <a:Key>somefield</a:Key>
                            <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">14</a:Value>
                        </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                        ... othter fields omitted for brievety ...
                    </AfterProperties>
                    <AfterUrl>Documents partages/myfile.pdf</AfterUrl>
                    <BeforeProperties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                    <BeforeUrl i:nil="true"/>
                    <CurrentUserId>14</CurrentUserId>
                    <ExternalNotificationMessage i:nil="true"/>
                    <IsBackgroundSave>false</IsBackgroundSave>
                    <ListId>96e3b5dc-7e94-4db9-b2cd-f0bbda1a59ab</ListId>
                    <ListItemId>64</ListItemId>
                    <ListTitle>Documents</ListTitle>
                    <UserDisplayName>Steve BEAUGÉ</UserDisplayName>
                    <UserLoginName>i:0#.f|membership|steve@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com</UserLoginName>
                    <Versionless>false</Versionless>
                    <WebUrl>https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mycoll</WebUrl>
                </ItemEventProperties>
                <ListEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <SecurityEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <UICultureLCID>1033</UICultureLCID>
                <WebEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
            </properties>
        </ProcessOneWayEvent>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Payload when copied from different site collections :

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ProcessOneWayEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/">
            <properties xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <AppEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <ContextToken/>
                <CorrelationId>cbf86ba0-0089-5000-5f44-207718e56ee9</CorrelationId>
                <CultureLCID>1033</CultureLCID>
                <EntityInstanceEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <ErrorCode>GetContextTokenError</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorMessage>Failed to get the context token for the remote event receiver url https://url/of/my/function.</ErrorMessage>
                <EventType>ItemAdded</EventType>
                <ItemEventProperties>
                    <AfterProperties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                        <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                            <a:Key>somefield</a:Key>
                            <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">14</a:Value>
                        </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                        ... othter fields omitted for brievety ...
                    </AfterProperties>
                    <AfterUrl>Documents partages/myfile.pdf</AfterUrl>
                    <BeforeProperties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                    <BeforeUrl i:nil="true"/>
                    <CurrentUserId>1073741823</CurrentUserId>
                    <ExternalNotificationMessage i:nil="true"/>
                    <IsBackgroundSave>false</IsBackgroundSave>
                    <ListId>96e3b5dc-7e94-4db9-b2cd-f0bbda1a59ab</ListId>
                    <ListItemId>64</ListItemId>
                    <ListTitle>Documents</ListTitle>
                    <UserDisplayName>Compte système</UserDisplayName>
                    <UserLoginName>SHAREPOINT\system</UserLoginName>
                    <Versionless>false</Versionless>
                    <WebUrl>https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mycoll</WebUrl>
                </ItemEventProperties>
                <ListEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <SecurityEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
                <UICultureLCID>1033</UICultureLCID>
                <WebEventProperties i:nil="true"/>
            </properties>
        </ProcessOneWayEvent>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Differences :

- when same site, my actual user account is set in the `UserDisplayName` and `UserLoginName`. When different sites, its system account
- When same site, `ContextToken` is provider, no error message. When different sites, `ContextToken` is empty, but `ErrorMessage` contains the error

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wonder if you see different behavior between an `-ing`  synchronous RER and an `-ed` asynchronous one.

Comment: This occurs both in `-ing` and `-ed` events